# A word for blowing air onto baby's tummy to make him (her) laugh

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What do you call the action when you press your mouth against baby's tummy and blow  air to make the baby laugh?

Comment: Motorboating *Whistles and walks away slowly*

Comment: I would change the word "into" to "onto" in the original question to make it a little more specific as to what is actually occurring.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That is typically referred to as [blowing raspberries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_a_raspberry):

> Blowing a raspberry, strawberry or making a Bronx cheer is to make a
>   noise signifying derision, real or feigned. It is made by placing the
>   tongue between the lips and blowing to produce a sound similar to
>   flatulence. In the terminology of phonetics, this sound can be
>   described as an unvoiced linguolabial trill. It is never used in
>   human language phonemically (e.g., to be used as a building block of
>   words), but the sound is widely used across human cultures.

Here is a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=blowing+raspberries+aby&oq=blowing+raspberries+aby&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5639j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=blowing+raspberries+baby+tummy) as they relate to baby tummies.

Comment: Although the resulting sound is very similar, I don't think this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Kevin did you follow the Google search I provided?

Comment: @Kevin - I wouldn't have thought so, either, but that Google search is pretty convincing. The ninja had me at "Mommy blowing raspberries into Ethan's tummy" on YouTube.

Comment: @cornbreadninja麵包忍者 I think that using this term could lead to confusion, or at least odd looks, as some people associate this term almost exclusively with derision.

Comment: The sound made on a belly, though referred to as a "Raspberry", is not produced as described in the Wikipedia article you cited. Just saying.  Don't ask me how I know. ;-)

Comment: And the word Raspberry comes from the Cockney rhyming slang 'raspberry tart', meaning 'fart', does it not? 'Blowing a raspberry' means farting.

Comment: @WS2, originally, yes, but at some point the meaning changed to "making a sound in imitation of a fart [but with the mouth]", and from there to "making a sound that happens to resemble a fart".

Comment: +1 The term "raspberry" for this is very common where I live (midwest USA).

Comment: I think the point of Kevin's comments is that the Wikipedia description cited by ninja doesn't support the claim that "raspberry" applies to an umbilicolabial trill. (It might apply, but the description doesn't show that.)

Comment: I have pretty much only ever heard this referred to as blowing rasberries.  (This is in KY)

Comment: @Kevin Growing up in the UK, this was always referred to as "blowing raspberries"

Comment: This is pretty distinct from "giving zerberts". As stated in the definition  you cite, it is characterized by having the tongue between the lips, and I would add, most often with the tongue protruding.

Zerberts are not like this at all and are as the OP stated, simply pressing the mouth against the tummy and blowing. The sound is made by the air escaping the blowers lips and the baby's tummy when pressed together somewhat firmly.

Comment: So many comments! I don't think any of them make this clear enough (LarsH comes closest, but not emphatically enough and with too-technical terminology): The biggest and clearest reason this isn't the best answer is that a raspberry is something a person typically does into the open air, not against someone's belly. The given Google search [begs the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question) because it includes "baby tummy". And to extend Jace's comment: From a pure mechanics standpoint, a raspberry uses the giver's tongue **instead of** the receiver's belly.

Answer (score 19):

Zerbert is what I have always heard it called.  Several sites of mixed authority confirm.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zerbert

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=zerbert

Comment: Never heard of this, and was totally confused about how it could have come about (corruption of Herbert? something to do with sherbet? what? why?) until I saw that it was originally spelled ZRBTT. If you want to describe this sound/action to someone who is not up on their 80's TV, you can probably use "ZRBTT" without further explanation, but "zerbert"... not so much.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znDI9UpFYKE

Comment: +1 But I've never heard it with the *r* at the end.  It's always been "Zerbet" where I came from.  (And for Bill Cosby as well).

Comment: I've always heard it as a zerbert. +1

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer. Here's an example of common usage that I hear frequently. For example, when addressing a toddler that understands spoken language I almost always hear: "I'm going to give you a zerbert!" Or, "I'm going to give you zerberts!"

Comment: @Marthaª If you watch the clip from the Cosby show, he very clearly enunciates the "r" at the end of zerbert many times. He omits it the second time, but every other time it's said with the "r".

Comment: This! (Although my parents pronounced it more like "zorbitt," as I recall.)

Answer (score 11):

Although there's evidence provided for "zerbert" and "blowing raspberries" providing the meaning you're looking for, it's worth mentioning that in many places, there isn't a particular word or expression for this except for blowing on a baby's belly.

If I (from California, US West Coast) went up to my sister and was like, "I'm gonna give you a zerbert," she'd probably think that I had a piece of candy or dish of sherbet (frozen non-dairy dessert, kind of like ice cream) to give her. On the other hand, if I said, "I'm going to blow raspberries," she'd then expect me to stick my tongue out at her and blow.

(**of note that the [urbandictionary link](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=zerbert)'s #4 definition provides the etymology of zerbert, which would be of use to read.**)

So, be advised, if you're going to use either of the above phrases – unless you qualify them with additional words like *"on the baby's tummy"* – you're just as likely to get blank stares or misunderstanding as you are to be understood. There's a big difference between *"blowing raspberries"* and *"blowing raspberries on a baby's belly."*

Comment: Sure, not everyone has heard "blowing raspberries" in the context of blowing on a baby's belly. Still, it's a correct answer. There are [dozens of published books](https://www.google.com/search?q=blowing+raspberries+aby&oq=blowing+raspberries+aby&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=blowing+raspberries+baby+tummy&safe=off&tbm=bks) that describe that gesture by saying "blowing raspberries on a baby's belly" (or similar phrasing). It may not be common knowledge on the street, but it appears to be a legitimate answer to the O.P.'s question.

Comment: @J.R., true, but even looking at the books (on the first page at least) they specify "blowing raspberries on baby's tummy" in the context. According to those, the act of blowing raspberries isn't constrained just to the tummy.

Comment: I took the liberty to modify your answer a little bit to clear up where we had a small disconnect. Feel free to roll it back if you don't think I made an improvement.

Comment: Aha, I approve this (change of) message.

Comment: The edits, especially the last sentence, significantly improve this answer.

Answer (score 8):

Growing up in western Pennsylvania we normally called it a "belly fart", because of it's similarity to the fartesque noise you could make by blowing against the palms of your hand.

Comment: +1 this is the only one that everyone will understand.

Comment: growing up in south central Pennsylvania, I never heard of "belly fart", but +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My family and I have always called it "belly-busting."

Answer (score 0):

In the south we called it 'blithering,' or blowing blithers. When you look at the definition of 'blithering idiot' it makes sense. It's an old term.

Answer (score 0):

My family has always called this *burbling*. Maybe it's a German heritage thing, or maybe someone in the family just decided on that name.

Answer (score -1):

My family always called it 'boozle' or 'boozling'. I'm going to ask my mom tomorrow how she remembers saying it.

Comment: Boozling! Damn it, autocorrect